# How can I contact a professor after few months?

Tags: publications, phd, research-process, professorship, australia

I have written Professor X (Australia) for a Ph.D. position with my CV (in June) and he asked for 3 reference names in return. I sent it. As I did not write him seeing any advertisement so I waited.
Meanwhile, I got busy with my own project and published two of my articles in highly reputed journals in these last three months.
I did not get any response from Professor X yet. Should I write him back asking if he's still interested in me? Is it ok if I send him the links to my recent articles?

Comment: _As I did not write him seeing any advertisement so I waited._ - I don't understand.  Are you saying he/his department don't have any positions for PhD students at this time?

Comment: yes, but he's a big shot, department head. We have known each other for the last 3/4 years. I mean at first, I wrote him for a masters thesis once, then I could not join him due to my visa issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would actually turn it around a bit.

> Dear Professor X
>
> We corresponded most recently a few months ago. I am still
> very interested in working with you toward a PhD if it can be made to happen. I haven't been idle in the interim. Following are links to my two most recent published articles.
> Please let me know if there is anything that I can do now to make this a reality.
>
> Thank you ...

Rather than ask if they are interested, just say that *you* are interested as well as active.

Answer (score 2):

> How can I contact a professor after few months?

I would recommend writing a short, concise, email. There are other questions on this site where you might find advice for writing such an email.

> Meanwhile, I got busy with my own project... I did not get any response from Professor X yet.

It is possible that your professor has also been busy and has other things on his mind.

> Should I write him back asking if he's still interested in me?

If you are still interested in working with him, then yes.

> Is it ok if I send him the links to my recent articles?

There should be no harm in including the links, but it might be good to phrase it in a way that requires no obligation on the part of the professor. Something as a progress update ("since we last corresponded, I have published this and this...") might be okay, but I would avoid asking him to read anything in particular.